# Updating highchart when sliding navigator

Tags: highcharts

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680794/highcharts-navigation-by-3rd-element-in-series-hidden-in-plot) fantastic answer to a question I had earlier today here on stackoverflow-

However, I am wondering if there is a way I can enable the highstock chart to update while I'm sliding the navigator (similar to the highstock demos)

I've attempted to change from afterSetExtremes to setExtremes to no avail

The [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wuwdonn/1/) provided by morganfree in the linked question above

```
events: {
  afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
    var points = this.chart.get('main-series').points;
    points.forEach(function(point) {
      point.update({
        y: e.min <= point.date && point.date <= e.max ? point.holdY : null
      }, false, false);
    });
    this.chart.redraw();
  }
}
}, {
type: 'linear'
}],

navigator: {
enabled: true
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to update data at the same time as you are moving navigator? If so, simply change Highcharts to Highstock chart. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dgjxb9vt/.

Comment: That was it! Thanks. Can't believe I missed something so simple.